# Pass session and location between two sub-domains?

Tags: sessions

We have two main sites (www.website.com, and ca.website.com) We utilize GEOip to redirect to the appropriate site for US/Canada.

We share the same catalog, back-end for both sites. However, it doesn't seem to share the Cart, nor the sessions between the two sites when you change.

We would like to have it so that, for example: Canadian goes to ca.website.com, and chooses to switch to the US site (www.website.com) if they were already viewing a product, to load that product page (and/or if they add a product to the cart, to "bring" that cart with them between each site).

I have enabled SID on the frontend but it doesn't seem to do much (or anything by the looks of it).

Something I did note: If I add someone the to cart, switch sites (in either direction) the cart isn't brought over, however if I switch back, the cart is still there with the previous items.

Is there a way to resolve this without needing to do custom coding to fix this issue?

Comment: I should also add, each store is its own website/store/storeview within magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 things you can check.

1. Be sure to set your Cookie Domain to `.website.com`, since your two websites in the example are `ca.website.com` and `www.website.com`.  You can change this in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Session Cookie Management -> Cookie Domain`. [image]
2. Set your "Share Customer Accounts" setting to "Global" so all of your customers will exist across all of your stores and not be divided by website.  This setting is in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Account Sharing Options -> Share Customer Accounts`.

[image]

Comment: I didn't have the . in front of my domain, but my share accounts was already set to global. Problem persists.