# Add to Magento2 cart from external site

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I am using Magento2 and need to add a product to the cart from a remote site. Same TLD, different subdomain.

ie `www.mainsite.com` add to `checkout.mainsite.com`

I was using the REST API and found that it actually uses sessions, which override other data when adding to a cart.

For example POST to `/rest/V1/guest-carts` will return a `cartID` and set the PHPSESSID cookie. If you include the `PHPSESSID` in subsequent POST to `/rest/V1/guest-carts/cartID/items` then the `cartID` is overridden and `PHPSESSID` is used instead.

It seems like the cart data is now tied to `PHPSESSID`, but if I go to `checkout.mainsite.com` there is nothing in the shopping cart, even though my `PHPSESSID` is still the same.

Can the API be used as is to AddToCart from a remote site, then go to Magento2 and view the items in the cart?

Answer (score 0):

Go to General, Web, Default Cookie Settings section, and change the Cookie Domain field to .yoursite.com (note the . before the domain name)

It seems your issue is that your session is not being shared between subdomains, which is not a bug itself but a feature used to enhance security. 
More info on [cookies](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-cookie-restriction-mode-guide-for-developers/) can be found here and a similar question for M1 can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54044/pass-session-and-location-between-two-sub-domains).

Comment: That is already setup correctly. Both cookie domains are .mainsite.com

Comment: So you are using 2 different Magento 2 installs?

Comment: Only checkout.mainsite.com is Magento. www.mainsite.com is another platform. We are trying to use Magento as a headless CMS.

Comment: I don't think you can combine headless with headed Magento versions. If you add to cart via the API you should get the cart via the API and the same goes for adding a product to cart via the headed Magento version.